# How to create a stored procedure in TSQLT Set up?

Tags: c#, tsqlt

I try to add new TSQLT in .NET solution. Some tests that I implemented use the same code and that's why I would like to create a stored procedure and call it from tests. But for some reasons I see only errors when insert working in SQL management studio code in the test .sql file.

I've tried to put the procedure creation code in the [SetUp](https://tsqlt.org/user-guide/test-creation-and-execution/run/) of TSQLT, but for some reasons, I see that it's not picking up by the runner.

Should my .sql file name be in format `classname.SetUp` as well or the procedure name should be in such format only?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To actually use the SetUp capability of tSQLt, you only need to add a stored procedure called SetUp within the test class(or schema in SQL Server terms).

For example if you have a test class called `testMergingCountryFromStaging` then you can create a SetUp stored procedure as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testMergingCountryFromStaging.SetUp
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Now fake the actual tables and
-- only those fields that are actually necessary
-- for stored procedure validation.
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = N'Country', @SchemaName = N'dbo';
EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = N'Country', @SchemaName = N'staging';

-- Initialize expected result and actual table
CREATE TABLE expected(CountryName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, ActiveForDelivery BIT NOT NULL);
END;
GO
```

Then, when running the unit tests of the class by executing `EXEC tSQLt.Run 'testMergingCountryFromStaging';`, the SetUp stored procedure will be executed by tSQLt first and then will resume with the execution of the actual tests.